# Type Error occurred when creating object after Upgrading to magento 2.1 to 2.4.3

Tags: error, upgrade, magento2.4

I have Upgraded my Magento 2.1 to 2.4.3 after upgrading I am facing some issues like

`Service with name "Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand" could not be created. Reason: Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Ind exer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand\Interceptor, ltrim() expects parameter 1 to be string, int given`

Not able to run the commands

`There are no commands defined in the "setup:di" namespace.`

I have tried below things

`sudo chmod -R 777 var pub`
`rm -rf generated/*`

But nothing is working. Below is the screenshot of the system error log file.

[image]

How to fix this error, Can I get some help?.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is showing after the data migration because some products or categories have duplicate rewrite URLs in the url_rewrite table

a) You can search the duplicate URL and rename/remove

b)

> vendor/magento/module-URL-rewrite/Model/Storage/DbStorage.php

Edit this file or overwrite this file

```
protected function insertMultiple($data)
            {
                try {
                    return true;
```

Note : after changes run the reindex command